# HTML Table Filtering

Tags: html, css

I have an html table and I want to let my users  filter out the rows given a criteria such as pages longer than x, genre is y etc by selecting multiple dropdowns and pushing a button .

How can I do that? What kind of coding do I need?

I am new to coding so I need some dummy explanations.

The table example is below.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Book Name</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Book Pages</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Genre</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">a</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">a</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">sss</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">a</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">dds</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">4</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">b</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ddd</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">5</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">b</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">fff</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">b</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This question is very broad - are you wanting to do this client side or server side? What have you tried to implement so far? If it's just client side filtering you should just be able to attach event listeners to the search form, and then hide/show table rows that match.

Comment: I have a website powered by blogger and I want to add thisfunctionality to a page so that users can search books acording to their criteria.

Comment: I suggest you: figure out how to embed a JavaScript script in a blogger page, then search for some introductory JS tutorials. After than, figure out how to show/hide table rows depending on a criteria, and then after that create a search form.

Comment: Is that (https://www.datatables.net/) what you want to achieve?

Comment: What server side language are you using? Do the books come from a database?